# no warnings in QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, compiler-warnings, flags

I can't see almost any warnings in my program.

My cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int ll = 100000000067;
    unsigned short sh = ll; //no warning here, why?

    cout << sh << " " << ll << endl;


    int s;  //warning only here: warning: unused variable ‘s’ [-Wunused-variable]

    return 0;
}
```

My pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

I try use project with cmake, but the results are this same.

Comment: What was the compiler that you used ?

Comment: in option -> build & run -> compilers I have only: auto-detected GCC 64/32 bit. I use 64bit by default.

Comment: What is your GCC version? Type `gcc --version` in terminal.

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to GCC documentation

> -Wconversion
>
> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes conversions between real and integer, like abs (x) when x is double; conversions between signed and unsigned, like unsigned ui = -1; and conversions to smaller types, like sqrtf (M_PI). Do not warn for explicit casts like abs ((int) x) and ui = (unsigned) -1, or if the value is not changed by the conversion like in abs (2.0). Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers can be disabled by using -Wno-sign-conversion.
> For C++, also warn for confusing overload resolution for user-defined conversions; and conversions that never use a type conversion operator: conversions to void, the same type, a base class or a reference to them. Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

For me your example with `-Wconversion` generates

```
~/main.cpp:9: warning: conversion to 'short unsigned int' from 'long long int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   unsigned short sh = ll; //no warning here, why?
                       ^
```

Comment: I'm surprised this is not covered by (any or all of) `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`!